# How to see a video through Flash?

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, flash

I can see this video through VLC: http://webtv.camera.it/cartelloaula.asx

But I want to see it through Flash. Is it possible?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be played in Flash.  Here's a tutorial from Adobe:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/learning_guide/video/part04.html

Modified steps from the article for your specific situation:

1. Select File >  Import > Import video. The Import Video Wizard is displayed.
2. Select "Already deployed to a web server" and enter the URL.
3. Click "Next".
4. Choose the skin you like and "Next"
5. Click "Finish"

Note that this is not streaming video.  This is just a plain old progressive download video.  Streaming involves using a server component that sends video packets requested by the client and can provide server side seek and pause functionality among other features.  When you just load a video onto a web server, the video is downloaded like any other asset (like an image), and played by the client.